# Rewrite $\sin^4 x$ so that it involves only the first power of cosine?

Tags: trigonometry

What I have so far:

rewrite the problem as a product of two squared terms: 
$\sin^2(x)\sin^2(x)$

Apply the squared identity for sine twice: 
$(1+\cos(x)) (1-\cos(x)) (1+\cos(x)) (1-\cos(x))$

Multiply the terms: 
$(1+\cos(x))^2 (1-\cos(x))^2$

Then they want me to apply the squared identity for cosine and then simplify.

How do I apply the identity when it is squared?

Thanks.

Comment: what is the "squared identity for cosine"?

Answer (score 2):

Good try! I suggest using this identity instead:
$$\sin^2 x = \frac{1}{2} \left(1-\cos 2 x\right).$$

That one will get you halfway. Next you'll need:
$$\cos^2 x = \frac{1}{2} \left(1+\cos 2 x\right).$$

Comment: They choose which identities they want me to use unfortunately.  They want me to use the squared identity in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

Does this lead down the required path?

$(\sin^2 x )^2 = (1-\cos^2 x)^2$

Apply $\cos^2 x = \frac12 (1 + \cos(2x)$ to get

$\quad = (1-\frac12 (1 + \cos(2x))^2$

$\quad = (\frac12(1 - \cos(2x))^2$

$\quad = \frac14(1 - 2\cos(2x) + \cos^2(2x))$

Similar to before, substitute $\cos^2(2x) = \frac12 (1 + \cos(4x)$ to get

$\quad = \frac14(1 - 2\cos(2x) + \frac12 (1 + \cos(4x))$

$\quad = \frac18(3 - 4\cos(2x) + \cos(4x))$

Comment: I think this guy was doing it right:[link](http://www.enotes.com/homework-help/rewrite-sin-4-x-that-involves-only-first-power-384936)   But instead of stopping they want me to apply the squared identity for cosine and then simplify.

Comment: What do you mean by the squared identity for cosine? That could be one of many things... Do you mean $cos^2 x = 1- sin^2 x$ or something else?

Comment: Or rather, could you edit your post to contain the original language of the problem?